# java.lang.numberformatexception when parsing string to input into database

Tags: java, mysql, parsing

I'm relatively new to Java and am trying to make a POS system with a checkout. I want to input invoices into a database by taking the values from a checkout table.

I have a table (jTable2) in which each of the items in the cells are objects. I have tried casting it to a string, and upon that failing, I used the toString() method, but I keep getting the same error. Here is my code

```
if(c<=itemcounter){
    String sql="INSERT into invoices(InvoiceID, ClientID, ProductName, ProductAmt, UnitPrice, TotalProductPrice) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Connection conn=MySqlConnection();

    PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstmt.setInt(1, InvoiceID);
    pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(cIDField.getText()));
    pstmt.setString(3, (String)jTable2.getValueAt(c, 1));
    pstmt.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(c, 3).toString())); //THIS IS THE LINE I NEED HELP WITH
    pstmt.setDouble(5, Double.parseDouble((String) jTable2.getValueAt(c, 2)));
    pstmt.setDouble(6, Double.parseDouble((String) jTable2.getValueAt(c, 4)));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

> java.lang.numberformatexception for input string "(string that is a parsed cell c, 4 of jTable2)"

I don't understand what I can do to fix it. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: What c;lass are your objects? They do not seem to be String.

Comment: Is it (c, 3) as you claim in the code or (c, 4) as it says below?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line: Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(c, 3).toString())

It get's the value from a table and converts it to an int. Guess what happens when the value retrieved is not an int? That's right, you get a NumberFormatException.

Create a safe helper method like:

```
private int safeConvertToInt(String value) {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(value);
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: Could not convert |" + value + "| to int");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

How safeConvertToInt behaves depends upon your needs. The above logs the error and returns the value zero. You may well want different error handling.

Comment: Read the question and the full answer. The user did not understand why they received the exception. The answer explains why. That is sufficient to answer the OPs question. How the error should be handled is up to the user. This is also explained in the answer. There is no way to know what handling is desired.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the text below the code so I remove my comment. Still unfortunate that you choose to post that particular code example in my opinion.